# Rails 3.2 routing error with scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This problem has taken all day of mine...

Well;

I'm just trying to put all of my administration pages inside an /admin directory and to receive them via domain/admin style only. I've tried to make it run with [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing%20this) guide.

According to that official guide, what I'm looking for is using `scope` in my `routes.rb` file. BECAUSE, I have used named routes tones of times inside my pages. I do not want my `program_path` named route to change `admin_program_path` since I have 28 different usage of it.

So I'm supposed to use `scope` instead of `namespace`.

Issue is: I can not make `scope` work with my project.

Here is my routes.rb

```
 scope "/admin" do

  get "access/login"
  get "access/index"

  match "access/login_attempt", to: "access#login_attempt"
  match "access/logout", to: "access#logout"

  resources :admin_users

  root to: 'programs#index'

  resources :programs
  resources :program_categories
  resources :program_subcategories

  resources :articles
  resources :pictures



  match '/kategoriler/:id' => 'program_categories#show'
  match '/kategoriler' => 'program_categories#index'
  match '/kategori/yeni' => 'program_categories#new'
  match 'program/yeni' => 'programs#new'
  match 'programlar' => 'programs#index'
  match '/progam_categories/select_category/:program_id' => 'program_categories#select_category'
  match '/program_subcategories/select_subcategory' => 'program_subcategories#select_subcategory'
  match '/program_subcategory/add_subcategory' => 'program_subcategories#add_subcategory'

  end
```

Here is my controller beginning :

```
class ProgramsController < ApplicationController
```

Just like told here:

```
If you want to route /admin/posts to PostsController (without the Admin:: module prefix), you could use
scope "/admin" do
  resources :posts, :comments
end
```

As a result, what am I getting?

This error message:

```
Routing Error

uninitialized constant ProgramsController
```

Whichever controller I try to access, error changes that way.. Such like `uninitialized constant ProgramCategoriesController` , `uninitialized constant ProgramSubcategoriesController` etc...

I've tried to place `application_controller` both inside admin folder and root of controllers directory... No way.

Where is my mistake here? :(

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `:module` parameter:

```
scope '/admin', :module => 'admin' do
  # ...
end
```

The assumption is that your controllers are in `Admin` module namespace, so they start with 'Admin::'.

**[EDIT]**

It is response to your problem in comments below about path conflicts. You can use `:as` parameter, for example:

```
scope '/admin', :module => 'admin', :as => 'admin' do
  # ...
end
```

You can check it with `rake routes`. All routes in the admin scope should now begin with 'admin_'

Comment: THANK YOU VERY VERY VERY MUCH!!! But this answer needs one more adition; with module parameter I needed to add Admin:: prefix to all of my controllers, please edit your answer for further searchers.

Comment: Ok, so you put your controllers manually to the admin dir? If you are generating your controllers with for instance `rails g controller admin/posts` they are named correctly from the start, that is 'Admin::PostsController'.

Comment: Err.. Another little question regarding this one. when I want to create a same name controller outside of Admin directory, there are several conflicts at helper files and css files for example. What should i do about this?

Comment: Views, assets, helpers, tests related to the admin module controllers should also be placed in proper admin subdirectories. Look at files created with for example: `rails g controller admin/hotels` (you can later destroy them with `rails d controller admin/hotels`). Views are in `app/views/admin/hotels`, helpers are in `app/helpers/admin/` etc. The same is with js and styles.

Comment: Well, scope is working fine but now I have another problem with this approach. I have controllers with the same name in my front end, when I try to use named routes inside them, I'm redirected to admin/ side.. For example' `<%= link_to "Category name", program_category_path %>` takes me to admin/program_categories/:id ... What should I do abou this? :|

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer but `namespace` does the same. I decided to use `namespace` instead of scope to avoid further conflicts. And I changed all of my admin files named routes manually :|